# Leaving node-fetch response without reading stream

Tags: node.js, fetch

Having the following code in a service (lets say on an express endpoint):

```
async function (res, req, next) {
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');

  await fetch('http://example.com/resource', { method: 'DELETE' });

  res.status(204).send();
}
```

What happens with the stream and connection opened by `node-fetch`?
Is it closed at some point? Or is it left open forever?

Is it better to do `(await fetch(...args)).text()` to consume the stream or its totally the same?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is closed by itself, the stream is just the response.

You should read the stream to validate if you didn't have any errors on your delete

Comment: While reading the stream, the connection is still open, why do you think its closed by itself?

Comment: They have one issue on github about that and I quote: TCP connection will be closed after request is complete, we send "connection: close" header.

Here's the link: https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/444